# Azure Dev Ops Pipeline 'This task is no longer installed.' Error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-task-groups

I was trying to fix an issue with my build pipeline in Dev Ops, but for some, reason all the tasks on all the pipelines have been removed. I get the error 'This task is no longer installed' on all tasks.

[image]

I have tried to revert the pipeline to the last good known configuration, with no success.

Also, I am unable to remove the task and reinstall them as they do not appear in the task list.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciate as it is driving me insane!

UPDATE

Here is the setting for the Pool

[image]

Comment: Can you navigate to the pipeline tab on top and check the settings there, in particular the agent pool info would be useful. Can you also check the settings for the agent (Phase 1)

Comment: I've updated the question with the pipline settings, the agent inherits from the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some help in the form of an Azure Support Ticket, the solution as simple.

Go to your **Organization Settings > Pipeline > Settings** and make sure that **Disable built-in tasks** is disabled

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reminding me Jane, I completely forgot to do that!